# How can I expand ranges like n-m, in Perl?

Tags: perl

Being a C developer I am fairly new to Perl. My requirement is that I need to convert the value like

```
3-6,9
```

to:

```
3,4,5,6,9
```

Also if in case the value is

```
3-6,9-18
```

to:

```
3,4,5,6,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18"
```

Comment: Do you have any script/line of code , to check what do you've had proved?

Comment: Are you tried any thing?

Comment: I cannot show the piece of code due to Confidentiality. I work in a company and i couldnt share code. I was unable to use the reg_exp. Ended up doing it in SQL(Oracle). But that was impacting my turn around time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Need to split twice to be able to detect missing range-end in both `3,9-12` and `3-6,9`

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

foreach my $string (q(3-6,9), q(3-6,9-12), q(3,9-12))
{
    my @ranges = split /,/, $string;   #/

    my @result;
    for (@ranges) {
        my ($beg, $end) = split /-/;
        push @result, ($end ? $beg .. $end : $beg);
    }

    my $res = join ',', @result;

    say $res;
}
```

prints<sup>†</sup>

```
3,4,5,6,9
3,4,5,6,9,10,11,12
3,9,10,11,12
```

This works for more ranges in your strings `1-3,8,10-12,...` etc. See [range operator](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators) (`..`)

Another way to handle a possibly missing end of range is

```
push @result, $beg .. $end // $beg;
```

where `//` is the [defined-or operator](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Logical-Defined-Or)

---

<sup>†</sup> The test of `$end` in the ternary operator is for "truth," and it fails for either of `undef`, `''` (empty string), `0` (number zero), and `"0"` (string).  In this problem `$end` should strictly be a positive integer and this is implicitly used. However, `undef` *is* expected and it is often better to be specific

```
push @result, (defined $end ? $beg .. $end : $beg);
```

On the other hand, testing for all truth-cases may catch unexpected ones as well (like `''`).

Note that "truth" in Perl has a few more interesting cases.  Thanks to [Silvar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6490359/silvar) for a comment.

Comment: I wish they could make downvotes seen, I would love for people to explain why they downvote something for no apparent reasons.. :|

Comment: Thanks @zdim worked like a charm. I was unable to post my code due to security reasons. Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: @VimalBhaskar as a matter of interest, we all have security risks, but we can simply replace sensitive data in our code by replacing it with dummy code.

Comment: As a matter of fact true, imagine changing the code for 10k lines? It will take a lot of time. I accept your point. But changing and replacing and putting back the code will take a lot of time. I believe i will do it next time.

Comment: @VimalBhaskar you have 10k lines of code with sensitive data..?? Anyways, remember, you do not have to post all the code, only the relevant code which makes it a [minimal, complete and verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. :)

Comment: Its a financial data and i dont know if all are sensitive data, Most of them are having SSN hard coded. Most of them date to 1999 code. SSN are hardcoded and so is the Address. The reason i wanted this piece of code pertains to the logic of SSN which is hard coded. If u work in a retirement and financial sector u will get to know that

Comment: I understand wat you are trying to imply. Check out my other questions and answers given. I always give question along with my workings. There are scenarios were u just cant give the code.

Comment: @VimalBhaskar It's all good, I am just trying to assist you with future questions.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard yes i understand. Next time probably i will try to mask my data and try to induce it in the question. Thank you.

Comment: I find the part with `($end ? $beg .. $end : $beg)` to be questionable coding practice. In this particular case you wouldn't expect `$end` to have zero value, but generally, you'd want to get in the habit of saying `(defined $end ? $beg .. $end : $beg)` instead.

Comment: @Silvar  "_In this particular case_" the `$end` _cannot_ be zero; that would make the beginning of the range negative  (against the basic assumption that it isn't).  As for the "_questionable coding practice_"  and  "_get in the habit_" -- I won't and I'd tell you not to either, because you often want to test for `''` or `0`, not `undef`, and often simply for "truth" (was that "_questionable_"?) Case to case. But, in this case it is about `undef` and it is better to be explicit. I'm adding a comment on it.

Comment: @Silvar  Since you are dispensing advice, I am obliged to inform you that, unfortunately, there is no silver bullet for this; a "_habit_" of using `defined` (meaning always, right?) will get you in nasty bugs just as well, if there is no attention to the problem at hand. What forms "good practices" -- which I am all for -- is a bit more elusive and complex.

Answer (score 0):

One way to expand the ranges:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @newvals = ();
my @retrns = qw(3-6 9 89-99);

findRanges(@retrns);

sub findRanges
{
    my @vals = @_;

    @newvals = map { if($_=~m/(\d+)\-(\d+)/) { ($1 .. $2); } else { $_; }  } @vals;
}

print join "\n", @newvals;
```